# Why is VS2010 in ASP.NET MVC2 giving me the wrong JQuery intellisense?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, intellisense

In ASP.NET MVC'S JQuery intelligence I am getting methods such as "**constructor**", "**toString**", etc.

**What do I have to do so that I get JQuery methods such as "css" and "click"?**

[alt text http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/tr7rto.png](http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/tr7rto.png)

If I just rightclick **on a plain .htm file** and open up Visual Studio, it **works** out-of-the-box:

[alt text http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/1u0q1uf.png](http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/1u0q1uf.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a reference to the jquery vsdoc js file - something like this:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

ScottGu made a post about this in relation to VS 2008 a while ago which is still a useful read for VS2010

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/21/jquery-intellisense-in-vs-2008.aspx

Comment: I copied and pasted that line into my Site.Master file and voila it works now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the jQuery VSDoc version in the project?

http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery

Look for the “Documentation: Visual Studio” link under each major version. Currently the latest available is against 1.4.1.